# Google not indexing a site that is not available to US visitors despite sitemaps and hreflangs

Tags: seo, google, google-search, google-index, international

I have a website that is forbidden for users in the USA, and all of the deep link pages redirect to the home page which has content explaining that the content if forbidden. For the rest of the countries it is normal.

My domain is indexed and showing the wrong meta title & description (saying the content is not allowed) and when I try to fetch some of my inner pages, says they are redirecting to the index one.
So I assume that it's the USA Google bot visiting my page.

Do you know how to fix that? Hreflang and sitemaps are made properly, but google won't show the correct content.

Comment: There is only one googlebot and that comes from California.

Comment: What closetnoc said.   You can't disallow traffic from the US if you want it indexed in Google.   And allowing Googlebot to crawl from the US while disallowing visitors from there would be considered cloaking by Google and cause Google to penalize the site.